# only top part of background image shown

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am adding an image using `background-image: url()`. It it only displays the top of the image but won't display the entire image.  I am not sure why it's doing that.  I was following an online instructor on Udemy, I have checked my code with his and everything is the exact same. Any suggestions????

Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/mverma45/pen/ZEWNQpZ?editors=1100

Code where I think the problem is but I am not sure?  Is it my spacing?

HTML

```
<section class="hero">
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(assets/css/img/main.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="hero-content-area">
        <h1>Mountain Travel</h1>
        <h3>Unmissable Adventure Tours Around the World</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Contact Us Now</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.hero {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
}

.hero .background-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #80a3db;
}
```

Comment: You set a height of `100px` to the `div` that has the background image. Therefore it will only show the top 100 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Your `background-image` div spans the whole width, but is only 100px high. If you use `background-size: cover` on a very "stretched" element like this, and don't add any other settings, the image will be stretched horizontally to fit the (full) width, and its height will be adapted proportionally, so it won't be distorted. With an image that has a common width/height proportion like 3:2, this will result in only a very small part of the image being show in the div, as you describe.

Possible solution:

1.) If its an abstract image and you don't care about the proportion being distorted, use `background-size: 100% 100%`

2.) Or use an image that already has approximately the height/width proportion of your div.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the height of the background image to anything larger, say height: 500px then the background image will be longer. you can experiment with the value to as you require. Hope Helps